# how to receive android broadcast in native NDK C++ program?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am working on an Android native C++ program which requires graceful shutdown before system shutdown or reboot.

I added a sigaction callback to catch the SIGTERM signal but the callback function wasn't invoke when I reboot the system.

So I want to add a broadcast receiver in my C++ program to receive reboot/poweroff system broadcast. But I didn't found any API about that.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1488

Comment: I have noticed that issue but no solution.

Comment: Realize that Android started as Java based API and any NDK C/C++ is in addition to the Java API/Android lifecycle. As implied in the link, you'll have to handle the Android API in Java/Kotlin and call into your code via JNI.